# Duvida com o operador ternário

Tags: c, c++

O que quer dizer a seguinte expressão:

```
struct Node *temp = root->left ? root->left : root->right;
```

Estou na duvida se ele está verificando a existência do ponteiro `root->left` ou comparando `*temp` com `root->left`, nesse caso, não teria que ser "=="?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é semelhante a um if:

```
struct Node *temp = root->left ? root->left : root->right;
```

e seria equivalente a fazer isto:

```
struct Node *temp;

if (root->left) {
    temp = root->left;
} else {
    temp = root->right;
}
```

Ou seja ele verifica se `root->left` é "verdadeiro":

```
 root->left ? ...
```

Se for define no `temp` o valor de **antes** do `:`:

```
 temp = <condição passou> ? root->left : ....
```

Se for "falso" definirá o valor **depois** de `:` para o `temp`:

```
 temp = <condição não passou> ? .... : root->left
```

Um exemplo mais simples:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a = 10;

    printf( "O valor de 'a' é igual a 1? Resposta: %s\n", (a == 1) ? "sim" : "não" );

    printf( "O valor de 'a' é igual a 10? Resposta: %s\n", (a == 10) ? "sim" : "não" );

    return 0;
}
```

O resultado será (teste no [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/RjYP2c)):

> O valor de 'a' é igual a 1? Resposta: não
>
> O valor de 'a' é igual a 10? Resposta: sim